# Search for Content Across SharePoint Sites

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Currently I'm using: /v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}') but I would like to search across all the sites I have access to.

Is there a Microsoft Graph API which can search a keyword on all sites a user can access in SharePoint without giving site id?

Answer (score 0):

There's no Graph API for a global content search at the moment.
However you can leverage the [SharePoint Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview).

Comment: additionally you can request this feature on the uservoice https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/filters/new?category_id=101632&query=search